# OData V4.01 and EF Core - Error selecting property of collection type

Tags: entity-framework-core, odata, odata-v4

Got an entity with a property of type string[]:

```
public class Version {

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("codes")]
    public string[] Codes{ get; set; }
}
```

Translated to Collection(Edm.String):

```
<EntityType Name="Version">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Codes" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
</EntityType>
```

Whenever I include it in a select query like:

```
?$select=Codes
```

This error is returned:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '$it' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Controller and EF:

```
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
public class VersionController : ODataController {

    private DbContext _context;

    public VersionController(DbContext context) {

        this._context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Entities.Version> GetVersion() {
        return this._context.Version;
    }
}
```

Either the table being empty or not, keeps failing. Any ideas? It seems a problem in EF translating that select query on collections from OData.

Comment: Add model to question.

Comment: Done. Tell me if something else useful is missing.

Comment: Try run `_context.Version.Select(x => new { x.Codes }).ToArray()` without OData. If it works.

Comment: It works. It returns the codes of all entries without problems.